# How to insert values from a form into a table using php on click of a insert button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having a html form where i have 3 fields(ID, NAME, BLOOD GROUP). And below that I've 3 buttons(INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE). And then i want to enter the values in the fields and when click on the INSERT button these values should be entered into a table through a PHP script. Similar respective actions must happen with UPDATE and DELETE also. Can anyone help me out?

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if (!$conn) {
    die("couldn't connect" . mysql_error());
}
echo 'connected successfully';
mysql_select_db('DB');

$id = $_POST['Id'];
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$blood = $_POST['BloodGroup'];
$order = "Insert into info(Id, name, BloodGroup) values ('$Id', '$Name', '$BloodGroup')";

$result = mysql_query($order);

if (!$result) {
    die('Input data failed' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Input data entered successfully';
mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: <?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn) {
 die("couldn't connect" . mysql_error());
}
echo 'connected successfully';
mysql_select_db('DB');
$id = $_POST['Id'];
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$blood = $_POST['BloodGroup'];
$order = "Insert into info(Id, name, BloodGroup) values ('$Id', '$Name', '$BloodGroup')";
$result = mysql_query($order);
if(! $result) {
 die('Input data failed' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Input data entered successfully';
mysql_close($conn);
?>

Comment: This is what i've done for insert. I don't know if it's correct or not.

Comment: First of all I would advise to change the mysql_ functions to PDO or mysqli since your code is prone to mysql injection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: And you could look into AJAX to make diferent calls when you press different buttons

Comment: Use mysql_select_db('DB') or die(mysql_error()); once

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure your form is submitting to the PHP script.

For this the INSERT button should be of `type="submit"`. Then you can debug your PHP script line by line. For UPDATE and DELETE you can use the same PHP script with the query strings. Ex - `?id=xx&action=update` OR `?id=zz&action=delete`. Then you can apply the code in your PHP script corresponding to the action.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_select_db('DB')` or `die(mysql_error());` once. and also your variable names are wrong.

Please Use

`$order = "Insert into info(Id, name, BloodGroup) values ('$id', '$name', '$blood')";`